# Listbox items to variant array - wrong number of columns

Tags: vba

According to MSDN, the `ListBox.List` property returns a variant array where each item in the list has a row number and a column number.

I have created an empty variant array to store the contents of a ListBox before it is cleared. The ListBox has 8 rows and 6 columns.

To copy the contents I am using the following code:

```
Dim TempArray() as Variant

Redim TempArray(0)

TempArray = FrmMain.Listbox1.list
```

What I notice in the locals window is `TempArray Variant(0 to 7, 0 to 9)` yet in the form design view, ListBox1 Columncount is definately 6.

Why am I getting 4 extra columns in the array?

Comment: Reproduced same results, interesting! All the extra ones are Null. Probably a bug? May need to ReDim to listbox columncount?

Comment: Just speculating, but `ColumnCount` might be the only the displayed columns, not the actual columns in the listbox source. In that case, in order to figure out the actual number of rows and columns. you'd have to use `UBound` with the appropriate dimension as a parameter.

Comment: Column 0 is populated via an array which is turn is populated from Row 1 of an excel worksheet though excel isn't the host application for this VBA macro (its complicated...). The remaining columns are populated by a subroutine with the last line which populates the listbox being: `.List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = "0.5" `. Perhaps there is an alternative to transfer the listbox items to the array using a loop to get correct boundaries?