# For each item in ListBox.list is returning 10 times the actual number of entries in the listbox (additional items are all null) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to access each item in a list box with a for each...loop
I am getting back 10 times the number of items in the list box - I get the actual items in the list box plus 9 times that of null

I wrote a stupid little program to see what was happening:

```
    itemCount = 0
    For i = 1 To 3
        CSESelector.CSESelectedBox.AddItem "argh"
    Next i
    For Each myItem In CSESelector.CSESelectedBox.List
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    Next myItem
    myListCount = CSESelector.CSESelectedBox.ListCount
```

the results are myListCount = 3 and itemCount = 30.  when I used .columncount, it was 1.  if I put in 5 items, I get 50; if I put in 2, I get 20

I know I can do a workaround (for i= 0 to .listcount-1), but I'm trying to get the for each...loop to work.  Any ideas of where I went wrong?
I'm using excel365 on windows 10, if that matters

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284189/listbox-items-to-variant-array-wrong-number-of-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a variable to the `List` property and take a look at it in the watch window, you will see it's a 2-d array with the same number of "rows" as your added items, but the "columns" size is always 10 (max. possible number of columns in a listbox), regardless of the listbox `ColumnCount` property:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Tim.  Looks like "For Each..." is out (unless I put in a line "if myitem = null then exit for")